# How to parse nested struct member variables in rust proc_macro?

Tags: rust, telemetry, rust-proc-macros

I am attempting to write a macro that will generate a telemetry function for any struct by using
#[derive(telemetry)] .  This function will send a data stream to anything provided that is io::Writable.  This data stream will be "self describing" such that the receiver doesn't need to know anything else about the data other than the bytes received.  This allows the receiver to be able to correctly parse a struct and print its member variables names and values, even if variables are added, removed, order changed, or variable names renamed.  The telemetry function works for non-nested structs and will print the name and type of a nested struct.  But I need it to recursively print the names, types, sizes, and values of the nested structs member variables.  An example is shown below as is the code.

Current behavior

```
use derive_telemetry::Telemetry;
use std::fs::File;
use std::io::{Write};
use std::time::{Duration, Instant};
use std::marker::Send;
use std::sync::{Arc, Mutex};
use serde::{Deserialize, Serialize};

#[repr(C, packed)]
#[derive(Debug, Serialize, Deserialize, Copy, Clone)]
pub struct AnotherCustomStruct {
    pub my_var_2: f64,
    pub my_var_1: f32,
}

#[derive(Telemetry)]
#[derive(Debug, Serialize, Deserialize)]
struct TestStruct {
    pub a: u32,
    pub b: u32,
    pub my_custom_struct: AnotherCustomStruct,
    pub my_array: [u32; 10],
    pub my_vec: Vec::<u64>,
    pub another_variable : String,
}

const HEADER_FILENAME: &str = "test_file_stream.header";
const DATA_FILENAME: &str = "test_file_stream.data";

fn main() -> Result<(), Box<dyn std::error::Error>>{
let my_struct = TestStruct { a: 10,
                                 b: 11,
                                 my_custom_struct: AnotherCustomStruct { my_var_1: 123.456, my_var_2: 789.1023 },
                                 my_array: [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10],
                                 my_vec: vec![11, 12, 13],
                                 another_variable: "Hello".to_string()
                                };
let file_header_stream = Mutex::new(Box::new(File::create(HEADER_FILENAME)?) as Box <dyn std::io::Write + Send + Sync>);
let file_data_stream = Mutex::new(Box::new(File::create(DATA_FILENAME)?) as Box <dyn std::io::Write + Send + Sync>);
    my_struct.telemetry(Arc::new(file_header_stream), Arc::new(file_data_stream));
let header: TelemetryHeader = bincode::deserialize_from(&File::open(HEADER_FILENAME)?)?;
    let data: TestStruct = bincode::deserialize_from(&File::open(DATA_FILENAME)?)?;
    println!("{:#?}", header);
    println!("{:?}", data);
Ok(())
}
```

produces

```
TelemetryHeader {
    variable_descriptions: [
        VariableDescription {
            var_name_length: 1,
            var_name: "a",
            var_type_length: 3,
            var_type: "u32",
            var_size: 4,
        },
        VariableDescription {
            var_name_length: 1,
            var_name: "b",
            var_type_length: 3,
            var_type: "u32",
            var_size: 4,
        },
        VariableDescription {
            var_name_length: 16,
            var_name: "my_custom_struct",
            var_type_length: 19,
            var_type: "AnotherCustomStruct",
            var_size: 12,
        },
        VariableDescription {
            var_name_length: 8,
            var_name: "my_array",
            var_type_length: 10,
            var_type: "[u32 ; 10]",
            var_size: 40,
        },
        VariableDescription {
            var_name_length: 6,
            var_name: "my_vec",
            var_type_length: 14,
            var_type: "Vec :: < u64 >",
            var_size: 24,
        },
        VariableDescription {
            var_name_length: 16,
            var_name: "another_variable",
            var_type_length: 6,
            var_type: "String",
            var_size: 24,
        },
    ],
}
TestStruct { a: 10, b: 11, my_custom_struct: AnotherCustomStruct { my_var_2: 789.1023, my_var_1: 123.456 }, my_array: [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10], my_vec: [11, 12, 13], another_variable: "Hello" }
```

The data format is length of variable name, variable name, length of variable type, variable type, variable num of bytes.

Required Behavior

```
TelemetryHeader {
    variable_descriptions: [
        VariableDescription {
            var_name_length: 1,
            var_name: "a",
            var_type_length: 3,
            var_type: "u32",
            var_size: 4,
        },
        VariableDescription {
            var_name_length: 1,
            var_name: "b",
            var_type_length: 3,
            var_type: "u32",
            var_size: 4,
        },
        VariableDescription {
            var_name_length: 16,
            var_name: "my_custom_struct",
            var_type_length: 19,
            var_type: "AnotherCustomStruct",
            var_size: 12,
        },
        VariableDescription {
            var_name_length: 8,
            var_name: "my_var_2",
            var_type_length: 3,
            var_type: "f64",
            var_size: 8,
        },
        VariableDescription {
            var_name_length: 8,
            var_name: "my_var_1",
            var_type_length: 3,
            var_type: "f32",
            var_size: 4,
        },
        VariableDescription {
            var_name_length: 8,
            var_name: "my_array",
            var_type_length: 10,
            var_type: "[u32 ; 10]",
            var_size: 40,
        },
        VariableDescription {
            var_name_length: 6,
            var_name: "my_vec",
            var_type_length: 14,
            var_type: "Vec :: < u64 >",
            var_size: 24,
        },
        VariableDescription {
            var_name_length: 16,
            var_name: "another_variable",
            var_type_length: 6,
            var_type: "String",
            var_size: 24,
        },
    ],
}
TestStruct { a: 10, b: 11, my_custom_struct: AnotherCustomStruct { my_var_2: 789.1023, my_var_1: 123.456 }, my_array: [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10], my_vec: [11, 12, 13], another_variable: "Hello" }
```

To reiterate, the current behavior correctly prints the variable name, type, size, and value for a struct with the Telemetry trait derived.  It prints the name, type, and size for a nested struct correctly, but it does not then print the names and values of the nested structs members which is required. The code is below, apologies for such a long post, I hope this is formatted well and clear, thank you in advance.

Directory Structure

```
src
 -main.rs
telemetry
 -Cargo.toml
 -src
   --lib.rs
Cargo.toml
```

main.rs

```
use derive_telemetry::Telemetry;
use std::fs::File;
use std::io::{Write};
use std::time::{Duration, Instant};
use std::marker::Send;
use std::sync::{Arc, Mutex};
use serde::{Deserialize, Serialize};

const HEADER_FILENAME: &str = "test_file_stream.header";
const DATA_FILENAME: &str = "test_file_stream.data";

#[repr(C, packed)]
#[derive(Debug, Serialize, Deserialize, Copy, Clone)]
pub struct AnotherCustomStruct {
    pub my_var_2: f64,
    pub my_var_1: f32,
}

#[derive(Telemetry)]
#[derive(Debug, Serialize, Deserialize)]
struct TestStruct {
    pub a: u32,
    pub b: u32,
    pub my_custom_struct: AnotherCustomStruct,
    pub my_array: [u32; 10],
    pub my_vec: Vec::<u64>,
    pub another_variable : String,
}
fn main() -> Result<(), Box<dyn std::error::Error>>{
    let my_struct = TestStruct { a: 10,
                                 b: 11,
                                 my_custom_struct: AnotherCustomStruct { my_var_1: 123.456, my_var_2: 789.1023 },
                                 my_array: [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10],
                                 my_vec: vec![11, 12, 13],
                                 another_variable: "Hello".to_string()
                                };
    let file_header_stream = Mutex::new(Box::new(File::create(HEADER_FILENAME)?) as Box <dyn std::io::Write + Send + Sync>);
    let file_data_stream = Mutex::new(Box::new(File::create(DATA_FILENAME)?) as Box <dyn std::io::Write + Send + Sync>);

    //let stdout_header_stream = Mutex::new(Box::new(io::stdout()) as Box <dyn std::io::Write + Send + Sync>);
    //let stdout_data_stream = Mutex::new(Box::new(io::stdout()) as Box <dyn std::io::Write + Send + Sync>);

    //let tcp_header_stream = Mutex::new(Box::new(TCPStream::connect(127.0.0.1)?) as Box <dyn std::io::Write + Send + Sync>);
    //let tcp_data_stream = Mutex::new(Box::new(TCPStream::connect(127.0.0.1)?) as Box <dyn std::io::Write + Send + Sync>);

    //let test_traits = Mutex::new(Box::new(io::stdout()) as Box <dyn std::io::Write + Send + Sync>);
    let start = Instant::now();
    my_struct.telemetry(Arc::new(file_header_stream), Arc::new(file_data_stream));
    let duration = start.elapsed();
    println!("Telemetry took: {:?}", duration);
    thread::sleep(Duration::from_secs(1));
    let header: TelemetryHeader = bincode::deserialize_from(&File::open(HEADER_FILENAME)?)?;
    let data: TestStruct = bincode::deserialize_from(&File::open(DATA_FILENAME)?)?;
    println!("{:#?}", header);
    println!("{:?}", data);
    Ok(())
}
```

main Cargo.toml

```
[package]
name = "proc_macro_test"
version = "0.1.0"
edition = "2018"

[workspace]
members = [
    "telemetry",
]

[dependencies]
derive_telemetry = { path = "telemetry" }
ndarray = "0.15.3"
crossbeam = "*"
serde = { version = "*", features=["derive"]}
bincode = "*"

[profile.dev]
opt-level = 0

[profile.release]
opt-level = 3
```

telemetry lib.rs

```
use proc_macro::TokenStream;
use quote::quote;
use syn::{parse_macro_input, parse_quote, DeriveInput};

#[proc_macro_derive(Telemetry)]
pub fn derive(input: TokenStream) -> TokenStream {
    let input = parse_macro_input!(input as DeriveInput);
    let output = parse_derive_input(&input);
    match output {
        syn::Result::Ok(tt) => tt,
        syn::Result::Err(err) => err.to_compile_error(),
    }
    .into()
}

fn parse_derive_input(input: &syn::DeriveInput) -> syn::Result<proc_macro2::TokenStream> {

    let struct_ident = &input.ident;
    let struct_data = parse_data(&input.data)?;
    let struct_fields = &struct_data.fields;
    let generics = add_debug_bound(struct_fields, input.generics.clone());
    let (impl_generics, ty_generics, where_clause) = generics.split_for_impl();

    let _struct_ident_str = format!("{}", struct_ident);
    let tele_body = match struct_fields {
            syn::Fields::Named(fields_named) => handle_named_fields(fields_named)?,
            syn::Fields::Unnamed(fields_unnamed) => {
                let field_indexes = (0..fields_unnamed.unnamed.len()).map(syn::Index::from);
                let field_indexes_str = (0..fields_unnamed.unnamed.len()).map(|idx| format!("{}", idx));
                quote!(#( .field(#field_indexes_str, &self.#field_indexes) )*)
            }
            syn::Fields::Unit => quote!(),
        };

    let telemetry_declaration = quote!(
        trait Telemetry {
            fn telemetry(self, header_stream: Arc<Mutex::<Box <std::io::Write + std::marker::Send + Sync>>>, data_stream: Arc<Mutex::<Box <std::io::Write + std::marker::Send + Sync>>>);
        }
    );



    syn::Result::Ok(
        quote!(
            use std::thread;
            use std::collections::VecDeque;


            #[derive(Serialize, Deserialize, Default, Debug)]
            pub struct VariableDescription {
                pub var_name_length: usize,
                pub var_name: String,
                pub var_type_length: usize,
                pub var_type: String,
                pub var_size: usize,
        }

        #[derive(Serialize, Deserialize, Default, Debug)]
        pub struct TelemetryHeader {
            pub variable_descriptions: VecDeque::<VariableDescription>,
        }


        #telemetry_declaration
        impl #impl_generics Telemetry for #struct_ident #ty_generics #where_clause {
            fn telemetry(self, header_stream: Arc<Mutex::<Box <std::io::Write + std::marker::Send + Sync>>>, data_stream: Arc<Mutex::<Box <std::io::Write + std::marker::Send + Sync>>>) {
                        thread::spawn(move || {
                             #tele_body;
                        });
            }
        }
    )
    )
}

fn handle_named_fields(fields: &syn::FieldsNamed) -> syn::Result<proc_macro2::TokenStream> {
    let idents = fields.named.iter().map(|f| &f.ident);
    let types = fields.named.iter().map(|f| &f.ty);
    let num_entities = fields.named.len();
    let test = quote! (
                let mut tele_header = TelemetryHeader {variable_descriptions: VecDeque::with_capacity(#num_entities)};
                #(
                    tele_header.variable_descriptions.push_back( VariableDescription {
                        var_name_length: stringify!(#idents).len(),
                        var_name: stringify!(#idents).to_string(),
                        var_type_length: stringify!(#types).len(),
                        var_type: stringify!(#types).to_string(),
                        var_size: std::mem::size_of_val(&self.#idents),
                    });

                )*
                header_stream.lock().unwrap().write(&bincode::serialize(&tele_header).unwrap()).unwrap();
                data_stream.lock().unwrap().write(&bincode::serialize(&self).unwrap()).unwrap();
        );
        syn::Result::Ok(test)
}

fn parse_named_field(field: &syn::Field) -> proc_macro2::TokenStream {
    let ident = field.ident.as_ref().unwrap();
    let ident_str = format!("{}", ident);
    let ident_type = &field.ty;
    if field.attrs.is_empty() {

                quote!(
                println!("Var Name Length: {}", stringify!(#ident_str).len());
                println!("Var Name: {}", #ident_str);
                println!("Var Type Length: {}", stringify!(#ident_type).len());
                println!("Var Type: {}", stringify!(#ident_type));
                println!("Var Val: {}", &self.#ident);
            )
    }
    else {
        //parse_named_field_attrs(field)
        quote!()
    }
}


fn parse_named_field_attrs(field: &syn::Field) -> syn::Result<proc_macro2::TokenStream> {
    let ident = field.ident.as_ref().unwrap();
    let ident_str = format!("{}", ident);
    let attr = field.attrs.last().unwrap();
    if !attr.path.is_ident("debug") {
        return syn::Result::Err(syn::Error::new_spanned(
            &attr.path,
            "value must be \"debug\"",
        ));
    }
    let attr_meta = &attr.parse_meta();
    match attr_meta {
        Ok(syn::Meta::NameValue(syn::MetaNameValue { lit, .. })) => {
            let debug_assign_value = lit;
            syn::Result::Ok(quote!(
                .field(#ident_str, &std::format_args!(#debug_assign_value, &self.#ident))
            ))
        }
        Ok(meta) => syn::Result::Err(syn::Error::new_spanned(meta, "expected meta name value")),
        Err(err) => syn::Result::Err(err.clone()),
    }
}

fn parse_data(data: &syn::Data) -> syn::Result<&syn::DataStruct> {
    match data {
        syn::Data::Struct(data_struct) => syn::Result::Ok(data_struct),
        syn::Data::Enum(syn::DataEnum { enum_token, .. }) => syn::Result::Err(
            syn::Error::new_spanned(enum_token, "CustomDebug is not implemented for enums"),
        ),
        syn::Data::Union(syn::DataUnion { union_token, .. }) => syn::Result::Err(
            syn::Error::new_spanned(union_token, "CustomDebug is not implemented for unions"),
        ),
    }
}

fn add_debug_bound(fields: &syn::Fields, mut generics: syn::Generics) -> syn::Generics {
    let mut phantom_ty_idents = std::collections::HashSet::new();
    let mut non_phantom_ty_idents = std::collections::HashSet::new();
    let g = generics.clone();
    for (ident, opt_iter) in fields
        .iter()
        .flat_map(extract_ty_path)
        .map(|path| extract_ty_idents(path, g.params.iter().flat_map(|p| {
            if let syn::GenericParam::Type(ty) = p {
                std::option::Option::Some(&ty.ident)
            } else {
                std::option::Option::None
            }
        } ).collect()))
    {
        if ident == "PhantomData" {
            // If the field type ident is `PhantomData`
            // add the generic parameters into the phantom idents collection
            if let std::option::Option::Some(args) = opt_iter {
                for arg in args {
                    phantom_ty_idents.insert(arg);
                }
            }
        } else {
            // Else, add the type and existing generic parameters into the non-phantom idents collection
            non_phantom_ty_idents.insert(ident);
            if let std::option::Option::Some(args) = opt_iter {
                for arg in args {
                    non_phantom_ty_idents.insert(arg);
                }
            }
        }
    }
    // Find the difference between the phantom idents and non-phantom idents
    // Collect them into an hash set for O(1) lookup
    let non_debug_fields = phantom_ty_idents
        .difference(&non_phantom_ty_idents)
        .collect::<std::collections::HashSet<_>>();
    // Iterate generic params and if their ident is NOT in the phantom fields
    // do not add the generic bound
    for param in generics.type_params_mut() {
        // this is kinda shady, hoping it works
        if !non_debug_fields.contains(&&param.ident) {
            param.bounds.push(parse_quote!(std::fmt::Debug));
        }
    }
    generics
}

/// Extract the path from the type path in a field.
fn extract_ty_path(field: &syn::Field) -> std::option::Option<&syn::Path> {
    if let syn::Type::Path(syn::TypePath { path, .. }) = &field.ty {
        std::option::Option::Some(&path)
    } else {
        std::option::Option::None
    }
}

/// From a `syn::Path` extract both the type ident and an iterator over generic type arguments.
fn extract_ty_idents<'a>(
    path: &'a syn::Path,
    params: std::collections::HashSet<&'a syn::Ident>,
) -> (
    &'a syn::Ident,
    std::option::Option<impl Iterator<Item = &'a syn::Ident>>,
) {
    let ty_segment = path.segments.last().unwrap();
    let ty_ident = &ty_segment.ident;
    if let syn::PathArguments::AngleBracketed(syn::AngleBracketedGenericArguments {
        args, ..
    }) = &ty_segment.arguments
    {
        let ident_iter = args.iter().flat_map(move |gen_arg| {
            if let syn::GenericArgument::Type(syn::Type::Path(syn::TypePath { path, .. })) = gen_arg
            {
                match path.segments.len() {
                    2 => {
                        let ty = path.segments.first().unwrap();
                        let assoc_ty = path.segments.last().unwrap();
                        if params.contains(&ty.ident) {
                            std::option::Option::Some(&assoc_ty.ident)
                        } else {
                            std::option::Option::None
                        }
                    }
                    1 => path.get_ident(),
                    _ => std::unimplemented!("kinda tired of edge cases"),
                }
            } else {
                std::option::Option::None
            }
        });
        (ty_ident, std::option::Option::Some(ident_iter))
    } else {
        (ty_ident, std::option::Option::None)
    }
}

#[cfg(test)]
mod tests {
    #[test]
    fn it_works() {
        assert_eq!(2 + 2, 4);
    }
}
```

telemetry Cargo.toml

```
[package]
name = "derive_telemetry"
version = "0.0.0"
edition = "2018"
autotests = false
publish = false

[lib]
proc-macro = true

# See more keys and their definitions at https://doc.rust-lang.org/cargo/reference/manifest.html

[dependencies]
proc-macro2 = ">= 1.0.29"
syn = ">= 1.0.76"
quote = ">= 1.0.9"
crossbeam = "*"
serde = { version = "*", features=["derive"]}
bincode = "*"
```

Once again, apologies for the lengthy post.  I hope this is clear and I believe this is everything to reproduce what I have and unfortunately I believe it is a minimum working example otherwise I would take more out for ease of reading/answering

I think if I could call handle_named_fields recursively on any Field that is a struct I would get the desired behavior. The only problem with this approach is that I don't see an obvious way to tell if a Field is a struct or not.  If I had a syn::Data it would be trivial, but I can't see how to make to this with a syn::Field.

Answer (score 1):

What you're trying is maybe a bit complicated for a SO question. I can only give an answer sketch (which would usually be a comment, but it's too long for that).

You can't parse "nested" structs in one macro run. Your derive macro gets access to the one struct it's running on, that's it. The only thing you can do is have the generated code "recursively" call other generated code (i.e. `TestStruct::telemetry` could call `AnotherCustomStruct::telemetry`).

There is one fundamental problem, though: Your macro won't know which struct members to generate a recursive call for. To solve that, you can either do the recursive call on all members, and implement `Telemetry` for a [buttload of existing types](https://docs.rs/serde/latest/serde/trait.Serialize.html#foreign-impls), or you ask the user to add some `#[recursive_telemetry]` attribute to struct members they want included, and fire only on that.

Comment: > `... or you ask the user to add some #[recursive_telemetry] attribute to struct members they want included, and fire only on that.` 

This seems the best approach to me but I don't see how `TestStruct` which depends on `AnotherCustomStruct` could suddenly access fields from that nested struct. It appears to me that the macros run within their own "bubble"

Comment: You should definitely treat macros as if they run into their own bubble (even if they technically don't, sometimes). What macros can do, though, is generate code in one bubble that relies on code generated in another bubble. So one bubble can generate code like `impl Telemetry for TestStruct { fn telemetry(recorder: T) { my_custom_struct.telemetry(recoder.subrecorder_for("my_custom_struct")) }}` because another bubble will generate `impl Telemetry for AnotherCustomStruct`. (This is what I mean by the second paragraph.)